# Write SSRS 2012 output to a folder in pdf format

Tags: sql, shell, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a task to run an SSRS report and export it to a folder in c drive. For the effort I tried to come up with below. I am running the statement below on the server where SSRS is installed. I want to be able to run this both on management studio as well as a job. Data driven subscriptions are not allowed for some internal reasons. So I had use XP_CMDshell.

I got the PrintPdfreport.exe from another team that is already using this functionality.

```
Exec master..XP_CMDSHELL 'C:\PrintPdfReport.exe "http://ServerName/Reportserver?/CIP Reporting/CIP Dashboard&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF" c:\Reports\DailyCIPDashBoard_20181029091327.pdf'
```

I am getting the access/authentication 403 error below. I am not sure how I can resolve this.

Output With Error below

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>
> at PrintPdfReport.Program.Main(String[] args) NULL

Comment: Have you researched HTTP 403?

Comment: Check that you have read access to that folder

Comment: I did research on the 403 but could find any. I have read/write access to that folder. THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the SQL Server service to run under an AD account (Domain\serviceaccount). Once you have that then add the account to reporting services with Browser access.

And grant that account read/write access to your target folder as well.